# Draw paper "cut" borders with html canvas or pseudo-elements

Tags: css, canvas, next.js, css-selectors, border

I'm trying to get a very specific "art nouveau" result on some paper surface because designers like to make us suffer. I'm working on a **NextJS project with MUI as my main design solution**, but have a lot of CSS going on in the back.

Here is what I'm trying to do (don't mind imperfections at the bottom of the frame):

[image: Visual result of a paper with multiple complex inner borders]

The main objective to achieve are those **inner borders with "cut corners"**, but I can't just use a plain image or .svg because they **need to have specific colors and sizes**.

The ideal would be that they fit their parent width and height in order to be fully responsive, because the Paper will eventually be turned into a component to contain text, images, etc.

**How do I make such borders?**

My actual code structure is quite simple:

```
<div className="mainWrapper">
   <div className="border1">
      // any text or content
   </div>
</div>
```

- Initially, I tried to make something with the `::after` pseudo-element and the `clip-path` property, but unfortunately it does not support borders, and calculations in order to make it responsive were way too complicated...
- I tried using the `<canvas>` with `useRef` (because my project uses SSR, so I had to wrap the canvas logic inside of a `useEffect`) but results were far from what I'm trying to do...

Comment: `I can't just use a plain image or .svg because they need to have specific colors and sizes` : SVG offers specific colors and sizes ?

Comment: They do, but it'll eventually distord the angles when the parent shrinks or extends - I'm trying to have angles with a fixed size while allowing the straight borders to extend if necessary...

Comment: IIRC SVG can also manage that, let me try some things and get back to you

Comment: Look into using border-image https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-image/

Comment: Indeed, SVG is not possible, some parts get cropped, sorry for wasting your time !

Comment: don't worry about it, thanks for trying! I think I've found a way to do it, I'll post it right there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a way but it's really tiring... (and complex because CSS):

```js
    const styles = {
        mainSurface: {
            width: "100%",
            backgroundColor: "blue"
        },
        bordersContainer: {
            backgroundColor: "blue!important",
            content: "''",
            position: "relative"
        },
        borderTL: {
            content: "''",
            position: "absolute",
            height: 32,
            width: 32,
            top: 16,
            left: 16,
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            borderRight: "4px solid",
            borderColor: "red",
            transform: "rotate(45deg)"
        },
        borderBL: {
            content: "''",
            position: "absolute",
            height: 32,
            width: 32,
            bottom: 16,
            left: 16,
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            borderTop: "4px solid",
            borderColor: "red",
            transform: "rotate(45deg)"
        },
        borderTR: {
            content: "''",
            position: "absolute",
            height: 32,
            width: 32,
            top: 16,
            right: 16,
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            borderBottom: "4px solid",
            borderColor: "red",
            transform: "rotate(45deg)"
        },
        borderBR: {
            content: "''",
            position: "absolute",
            height: 32,
            width: 32,
            bottom: 16,
            right: 16,
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            borderLeft: "4px solid",
            borderColor: "red",
            transform: "rotate(45deg)"
        },

        borderLeft: {
            position: "absolute",
            content: "''",
            height: "calc(100% - 104px)",
            width: 32,
            top: 52,
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            borderRight: "4px solid",
            borderColor: "red",
        },
        borderRight: {
            position: "absolute",
            content: "''",
            height: "calc(100% - 104px)",
            width: 32,
            top: 52,
            right: 0,
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            borderLeft: "4px solid",
            borderColor: "red",
        },
        borderTop: {
            position: "absolute",
            content: "''",
            height: 32,
            width: "calc(100% - 104px)",
            top: 0,
            left: 52,
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            borderBottom: "4px solid",
            borderColor: "red",
        },
        borderBottom: {
            position: "absolute",
            content: "''",
            height: 32,
            width: "calc(100% - 104px)",
            bottom: 0,
            left: 52,
            backgroundColor: "transparent",
            borderTop: "4px solid",
            borderColor: "red",
        },
        contentBox: {
            height: "100%",
            width: "100%",
            py: 6,
            px: 8,
            position: "relative"
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
           <Box sx={styles.mainSurface}>
               <Box sx={styles.bordersContainer}>
                   <Box sx={styles.borderTL}></Box>
                   <Box sx={styles.borderTR}></Box>
                   <Box sx={styles.borderBL}></Box>
                   <Box sx={styles.borderBR}></Box>
                   <Box sx={styles.borderLeft}></Box>
                   <Box sx={styles.borderRight}></Box>
                   <Box sx={styles.borderTop}></Box>
                   <Box sx={styles.borderBottom}></Box>
                   <Box sx={styles.contentBox}>
                       {props.children}
                   </Box>
               </Box>
           </Box>
        </>
    )
```

Giving something like this, clean and responsive:

[image]

Now, adding another "classic" bordered frame will be easier.
Thanks to anyone who tried to help! I hope this'll be useful to someone else in the future!

I'll try to optimize it and upload it somewhere eventually...

Comment: It's a bit nasty having to add so much to the DOM which doesn't otherwise have a meaning. Did you try linear-gradients?

Comment: The thing with linear-gradients is that it systematically creates imperfections around the angles, especially when resizing the box (some angles don't touch - others overlap weirdly), plus it forces to often deal with half-pixels measurements. 

While this solution is not optimal for adding so much to the DOM, it appears to be the most efficient to obtain a clean and responsive result (but changing the border width forces to recalculate everything...)

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done with one after pseudo element and linear gradients

HTML:

```
<div class="container">Lorem Epsum</div>
```

Try this codepen:

https://codepen.io/Starnas/pen/rNQoXvG?editors=1100

Comment: I totally didn't know we could do this using gradients! The angles are still a little bit off sometimes but this is detail - thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have an online generator for the difficult shape and the other one should be easy: https://css-generators.com/custom-corners/

```css
.box {
  width: 400px;
  aspect-ratio: 2;
  margin: 50px;
  position: relative;
}
.box:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  background: red;
  clip-path: polygon(0 50.00px,50.00px 0,calc(100% - 50.00px) 0,100% 50.00px,100% calc(100% - 50.00px),calc(100% - 50.00px) 100%,50.00px 100%,0 calc(100% - 50.00px),0 50.00px,3px  calc(50.00px + 1.24px),3px calc(100% - 50.00px - 1.24px),calc(50.00px + 1.24px) calc(100% - 3px),calc(100% - 50.00px - 1.24px) calc(100% - 3px),calc(100% - 3px) calc(100% - 50.00px - 1.24px),calc(100% - 3px) calc(50.00px + 1.24px),calc(100% - 50.00px - 1.24px) 3px,calc(50.00px + 1.24px) 3px,3px calc(50.00px + 1.24px));
}

.box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  inset: 10px;
  border: 3px solid red;  
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Wow, this thing is a lifesaver! Thank you!